# Undefined type 'Auth'.intelephense(P1009)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, visual-studio-code, laravel-10

Using Laravel 10 and VS Code this line was considered error:

```
Auth::routes();
```

VS Code says:

```
Undefined type 'Auth'.intelephense(P1009)
```

But no problem in the webapp.

I've already tried to do:

```
CTRL + SHIFT + P --> digit "Index workspace" --> Enter
```

but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your **routes/web.php** or, Where you are applying **Auth**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have not imported the "AUTH" package. To solve this you will need to add the following to your imported dependencies in your "routes/web.php":

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: This answer has already been given, and accepted.